# <header> tag not recognized in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html, cordova

I'm facing awkward scene here. I'm working on phonegap (cordova) 2.5.0 app and coding it in Eclipse. I want to use `<header>` tag to set some heading text.

```
<div id="headerdiv">
        <header>
        <h1>The Heading</h1>
         </header>
    </div>
```

But eclipse is showing cross icon saying

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Warning: discarding unexpected <header>
- Error: <header> is not recognized!
```

The html is properly structured and no brackets or closing tags are missed out. And the same code is error free if in Dreamweaver CS6.
What does this mean?

Comment: It looks like Eclipse thinks you are editing a .java file instead of a .html file? Make sure the file you are editing is .html. If this doesn't help, can you post the code? `Multiple markers` usually means more then one thing is wrong with the code.

Comment: I've added the code in the question..

Answer (score 4):

Header is an html5 element... does your html file start with the following?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

(So that Eclipse knows it is a html5 format to do proper validation)?

Comment: Yes I have started off with this itself.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents. When i tried to work with PhoneGap in Eclipse, i discovered that the html files were saved with the `world` icon, to view my HTML files, i had to right click and select `Open With > Text Editor`. I didn't like it so i installed the html plugin for Eclipse, that was when i started having this problem with my `</form>, </fieldset>...` tags. My HTML files already stared with `<!DOCTYPE html>` so Simon's suggestion didn't work for me. I tried deleting all the closing tags that were flagged but this only created new problems as my `HTML` pages were not rendered correctly. The only way out for me was to edit my `HTML` in `WebStorm` and copy them to `Eclipse` as i worked (after tearfully deleting the HTML plugin, and HTML files that used the plugin of course).

Answer (score 1):

Check that your html document starts:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The meta tag is also important.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - had   **Error: `<section>` is not recognized!; Warning: discarding unexpected `<section>`** in this code snippet:

```
<...some code>
<a class="navbar-right navbar-img" href="#"><img src="img/Angular.png     alt=""></a>

     </div>
</div>

<section ng-controller="NgTodoCtrl as ctrl"> 
<some code..>
```

it just wouldn't accept that **section** for nothing in the world. All code down from there turned red.

and why? because i forgot to close the quote in `<img src="img/Angular.png alt="">` it should be `<img src='img/Angular.png alt=""'>`

I added the quote and problem went away. See if you forgot to close some brackets/quotation marks/etc above from the issue.